# Cannot read property 'add' of undefined discord.js warm

Tags: discord.js

Heres the code It was working when it was running on my pc but now i uploaded it to replit it gives me this error and idk how to fix it

Heres the full error
node:352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at Object.run (/home/runner/PITOOOOOAOAOA/commands/moderation/warn.js:28:15)
at Client. (/home/runner/PITOOOOOAOAOA/index.js:97:13)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Color } = require("../../config.js");
const db = require('quick.db');

module.exports = {
  name: "warn",
  aliases: [],
  description: "Warnear  A  un Usurop!",
  usage: "Warn <Mention User> | <Reason>",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    //Start
    

        if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS"))
      return message.channel.send(
        `No tienes permiso `
      );
    
    let Member =
      message.mentions.members.first() ||
      message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

    if (!Member) return message.channel.send(`Profavor menciona a Menciona a un usuario `);

    let Reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    client.db.add(`Warnings_${message.guild.id}_${Member.user.id}`,1);

    let Warnings = client.db.get(
      `Warnings_${message.guild.id}_${Member.user.id}`
    );

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(Color)
      .setTitle(`Miembro Warneado! <a:686209726878449747:891459309987328041> `)
      .addField(`Moderador`, `${message.author.tag} (${message.author.id}`)
      .addField(`Miembro Warneado!`, `${Member.user.tag} (${Member.user.id})`)
      .addField(`Now Member Warnings`, Warnings)
      .addField(`Razon`, `${Reason || "No se proporcionó ninguna razón!"}`)
      .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
      .setTimestamp();

    message.channel.send(embed);

    //End
  }
};
```

Comment: It means `client.db` is undefined, we can't help you more with the code you gave us.

Comment: ^ Agreed can you send the code where you define the value ``db`` in client

Comment: thx i got it to work

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it lol i didnt define the client.db all i had to do is change client.db to db and it worked

```
let Warnings = db.get(
      `Warnings_${message.guild.id}_${Member.user.id}`
    );
```